# One way binding angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have a list of employees in a `select`, where the user can pick an employee and edit its details. Then he triggers an ajax call through a button, so the server can update the record in the DB.

I am binding with `ngModel` the fields and the data from my list of employees, but it is problematic if the update fails on the database side, because my list of employees is updated through the two way binding.

Is there a way to initialize my fields when the user picks an element in the select and update my employee list only when I get response?

Here is my explicit code from my directive (view):

```
select(ng-model='selectedEmployee' ng-options="employee.name for employee in employees")

form(role='form')
        input(type='input' ng-model='selectedEmployee.userId')
        input(type='input' ng-model='selectedEmployee.name')
        button (type='button' ng-click='updateEmployee()') update
```

and the directive

```
app.directive('employeeList', ['employeeServices',

    function(employeeServices) {
        var employeeListController = function($scope) {
            employeeServices.getEmployees()
                .success(function(result) {
                    $scope.employees = result.data
                })
                .error(function(err) {
                })

            $scope.selectedEmployee = null
            $scope.updateEmployee = function() {
                employeeServices.updateEmployee({
                    userId: $scope.selectedEmployee.userId,
                    name: $scope.selectedEmployee.name
                })
                    .success(function(data) {
                    //I want to update my $scope.employees here
                    })
                    .error(function(data) {
                    //Otherwise I show some error message
                    })
                    .then(function() {
                        $scope.selectedEmployee = {}
                    })
            }
        }

        return {
            ...
            controller: employeeListController
        }
    }
])
```

**Solution**

So in order to solve the problem I used `angular.copy` along with `ng-change`. I've added `ng-change` to the select, where I copied the `selectedEmployee` to `selectedEmployeeDirty` that I supplied as model for my form. Then in the service's callback I updated the `selectedEmployee`.

Comment: Very simple. Object, in javascript, are shared throught a "reference". In fact, this is a C pointer - or something like that -, how share the memory location of your object. If you do this:
var a = {}, b = a; a.toto = true; console.log(b);
You will see b.toto = true in the console.

Keep that in mind. Now, how can we isolate your edited object, without updating the original one? Make a copy! angular.copy is a friend, and would duplicate every properties of src to the dst. Use the ng-model as you did, save change, and, only on callback, update the original one :-)

Comment: @Nico Why not make that an answer instead of a comment?

Comment: Cause I think I don't have right :) I'll try to update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very simple. Object, in javascript, are shared throught a "reference". 
In fact, this is a C pointer - or something like that -, how share the memory location of your object. 
If you do this:

```
var a = {}, 
b = a; 
a.toto = true; 
console.log(b);
```

You will see

```
b = { toto: true }
```

Keep that in mind.

Now, how can we isolate your edited object, without updating the original one? Make a copy! angular.copy is a friend, and would duplicate every properties of src to the dst.

Use the ng-model as you did, save change, and, only on callback, update the original one :-)

Comment: The idea is nice, but please note the `select` in my view. Could you write out the exact solution, since I have trouble figuring out how to update the `input` fields only when someone selects an item from employees. Where do I put the copy? Everything is done in the background through angular.

Comment: OK, I found a solution using your idea. I'll accept it and update my question with the solution.